# SpriteKitNode not moving

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a SKSpriteNode which is not moving as expected:

In my GameScene.swift

```
var ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Sphere")
ball.position = CGPointMake(frame.size.width/2, frame.size.height/2)
ball.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
self.addChild(ball)

var impulse = CGVectorMake(0.5, 0.0)
ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(impulse)
```

Now, I am able to see the sphere in the middle of the screen, but it is not moving as expected, why?

Not even with:

```
ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thoughts I have to check the `PhysicsBody` has been initialised - perhaps your optional ? unwrap is failing.  So add in the following line below your var ball declaration:

```
ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ball.frame.size)
```

It may not be the ideal physics body shape, but this should allow your ball to move as per the impulse.